# How to check if the candle is the largest one in Pine-Script?

Tags: pine-script, candlesticks

I wanna to make pine script code to **check is that candle the largest one of the previous 50 candles** and color it yellow
i tried hard ,but i can't

Comment: What have you tried? Shwo us your attempt. What do you mean by largest candle? Largest in terms of solid body, or in terms of the difference between high and low?

Comment: i delated all sorry , i mean the differance between high and low (high-low) not the solid body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
r = high - low
barcolor(rising(r,50) ? color.yellow : na)
```