# Can i get data of specific old candles in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart, cryptocurrency, forex, candlesticks

I wanna to get data of old candles such as high, low , close , open

Can i get the data of candle 1 and 2 ?

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw9qZ.png)

Note :
the code in this link that i use to select those candles

[How to check if the candle is the largest one in Pine-Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582115/how-to-check-if-the-candle-is-the-largest-one-in-pine-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `valuewhen` function, if you want the high price you can use:

```
valuewhen(rising(r,50),high,0)
```

for "candle 2" in your image, for candle 1 use

```
valuewhen(rising(r,50),high,2)
```